# Quelle est la difference entre "ainsi" et "comme ça" ?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot, adverbes

Indila a chanté

> **Ainsi bas la vida**

Je me suis demandé si on pouvait aussi dire:

> **La vie va comme ça**

Ca ne sonne pas aussi bien à mes oreilles mais je sais pas expliquer pourquoi...

> J'ai jamais vu une voiture qui est belle comme ça

Personne ne dirait:

> J'ai jamais vu une voiture qui est ainsi belle

Mais pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Ainsi bas la vida*** n'est pas facilement compréhensible.

Vu que *la vida* signifie *la vie* en espagnol, je comprends cette expression comme une variante libre de l'expression française bien connue :

> Ainsi va la vie. (en espagnol: *Así va la vida*)

Cependant, si le *b* de bas peut-être compris comme la prononciation du *v* espagnol, le *s* à *bas* est lui difficilement explicable et en toute logique, il aurait fallu écrire:

> *Ainsi ba la bida* ...

ce qui est nettement moins agréable à l’œil.

Si *bas* doit garder son son sens habituel (l'opposé de *haut*), l'expression *ainsi bas* n'est pas idiomatique. On dit *aussi bas* et il faudrait alors comprendre ***bas comme ça, la vie***, ce qui semble être le consensus de la plupart des traductions des paroles de cette chanson mais qui peut laisser perplexe :

> [That's how life lows](https://lyrics-on.net/en/1006285-ainsi-bas-la-vida-lyrics.html)
>
> [Così che si abbassa la vita](https://www.musixmatch.com/fr/paroles/Indila-2/Ainsi-bas-la-vida/traduction/italien)

Certaines traductions en espagnol comprennent l'expression comme il me semble qu'il le faut :

> [Así va la vida](https://lyricstranslate.com/es/ainsi-bas-la-vida-as%C3%AD-va-la-vida.html)

On peut traduire :

> Ainsi va la vie

par :

> La vie va comme ça

mais ce n'est pas aussi idiomatique.

Pour ce qui est de la dernière question, personne ne dirait :

> J'ai jamais vu une voiture qui est **ainsi** belle

car dans ce cas, c'est **aussi** qu'on utilisera :

> Je n'ai jamais vu de voiture [qui soit] **aussi** belle.

Comment: merci pour le reponse, mais je le savais (que c'est un mix de francais et espagnol). Je me demande si on pourra aussi dire: **la vie va comme ça** en lieu de **ainsi va la vie**

Comment: *Verstanden !* La prochaine fois, mieux vaudra choisir une phrase en français plutôt qu'une phrase unique en son genre comme celle là... :-)

Comment: Danke! :D tu as raison....mais ma question est toujours si les deux ("la vie va comme ça" et "ainsi va la vie") sont correct - pardon pour mon mal français

Comment: J'y ai répondu !

Comment: ah voila je vois! Merci bien!